# Getting built in account from environment variables in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install something into our app pool but when I use environment variables instead of string it doesn't map to the correct built in account.

Example:

```
if (-not (Test-Path env:USER))
{
    $user = 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
}
else
{
    $user = $env:USER
}

if ((Test-Path env:USER) -and ($env:USER -eq $user))
{
    Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$($webAppPool) -name processModel `
                                                  -value @{userName="$($user)";password="$($pwd)";identitytype=3}
}
```

This gives the app pool identity NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. However it is not the real one, those show up as just NetworkService in the app pool.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There isn't enough information here. I see you are setting the `$user` variable but where in your code do you try to apply this to an app pool, and what error do you get? Please provide a [mcve] for this.

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough information trying to not give away inappropriate details.```if ((Test-Path env:USER) -and ($env:USER -eq $user))
{
    Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$($webAppPool) -name processModel `
                                                  -value @{userName="$($user)";password="$($pwd)";identitytype=3}
}
```. This gives the app pool identity NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. However it is not the real one, those show up as just NetworkService in the app pool.

Comment: Can you edit that into your question?

Comment: Is `$env:USER` something set in your organization? That is not a standard environment variable. I don't see anything glaringly wrong here other than an unnecessary use of subexpressions in strings, which shouldn't be causing your issue.

Comment: The environment var USER is something from our organization yes.

Comment: One thing I do see is that if `$env:USER` isn't set, you set the `$user` variable to `NETWORK SERVICE` but you still check that `env:USER` is set later on - which it won't be, because it wasn't set in the first place.